# UNION and JOIN 3 tables, One of them doesn't have the same rows number

Tags: php, sql

for a query like this

```
$query = "
SELECT t1.title, t1.content, t2.image, t2.tags
FROM blog1posts t1, blog1imagestags t2 
WHERE id = :id

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.title, t1.content, t2.image, t2.tags
FROM blog2posts t1, blog2imagestags t2 
WHERE id = :id

UNION ALL //THE PROBLEM

SELECT t1.title, t1.content, t2.tags
FROM blog2posts t1, blog3imagestags t2
WHERE id = :id
";
```

How can i UNION or JOIN the last part with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this (add a dummy field in third UNION):

```
SELECT t1.title, t1.content, t2.image, t2.tags
FROM blog1posts t1, blog1imagestags t2 
WHERE id = :id

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.title, t1.content, t2.image, t2.tags
FROM blog2posts t1, blog2imagestags t2 
WHERE id = :id

UNION ALL 

SELECT t1.title, t1.content, '' AS image, t2.tags
FROM blog2posts t1, blog3imagestags t2
WHERE id = :id
```

Comment: Wouldn't that slow the performance? Or does that make it skip the process at this field?

Comment: What do you mean with "make it skip the process at this field"?

Comment: As if the process won't read it, Like in the `DB` it won't go searching for `' '` in it, Even tho the row itself doesn't exist.

Comment: It simply put a "fixed result", a constant, (a blank or whatever you want) in image.  The other columns are extracted from the tables.

Comment: So that won't have any effect on the performance? Or the effect of it is lesser than typing a 2nd query?

Comment: I don't think it slows performances.  Anyway, what do you mean with "typing a 2nd query?".  If you mean to execute two separate queries and then using application to merge the result, this one should slow performances.